# While running code for spring mvc I'm having a 404 error " How to fix it?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am writing my first hello world application in spring mvc and getting the error.It should print the string "i am here" on the console but It is giving an http 404 error = "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists" don't know where is the error

here is the controller class

```
@Controller
public class AddController {
@RequestMapping("/add")
public void add()
{
    System.out.println( "I am here");
}
```

here is the **hp-servlet.xml** file

```
<ctx:annotation-config/>
<ctx:component-scan base-package="com.hp.demomvc.*">
    </ctx:component- scan>
<bean id = "viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>

</bean>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

here is the set of dependencies in **pom.xml** file
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-context
            4.1.8.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and here is the **web.xml** file

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `contextConfigLocation` in the `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/hp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: can you tell me some other solution for this problem??